# Issues with exporting a database file from an android app

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have an app that makes a SQLite database. I'm having trouble being able to export that database. I'm just trying to export it into a file onto the phone. My end goal is being able to email that file and then being able to import that file using the app. But that problem is for another day.

After I push the export button and check the phone for the database backup, I can't find the file, even with a search.

I'm pretty new yet to saving files, so I'd like to just see if I'm doing something obviously incorrect in this method. The tutorials I'm going through so far haven't helped me in pointing out the error.

Here is my export database method:

```
private void exportDB() {
    File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    FileChannel source=null;
    FileChannel destination=null;
    String currentDBPath = "/data/"+ "com.example.jeremy.sqlwine" +"/databases/"+ "wines.db";
    String backupDBPath = "wines.db";
    File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
    File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I have also added the permissions in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

---

**EDIT: Here is what ended up fixing it.**

I was able to get this because the user Hamed Nabizadeh kindly helped me out through chat for a while.

He helped troubleshoot and figured out that I was missing the request for the permissions in the java code. I just had to add this code to the MainActivity and it started working.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void exportDB(File db) {
        InputStream is;
        OutputStream os;
        try {
            File dest = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), db.getName());
            is = new FileInputStream(db);
            os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            is.close();
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Simply call:

```
exportDB(getDatabasePath("wines.db"));
```

NOTE: `In Android >= 6 Don't forgot to request permission at runtime`

Comment: The "context" in "new File(context.getDatabasePath("wines.db"))" is red and says "Cannot resolve symbol "context". And also, "(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());" is underlined and says "Cannot resolve constructor 'File(java.io.File)"

Comment: @andrdoiddev if you called method from activity, no need to call context

Comment: I want the exportDB method to be called when they push the "Export List" button that is on the top action bar. I can't get it to figure out the context. Here is a link to the button: https://pastebin.com/vu9UHKzZ . I'm sorry that I don't quite get this all yet. I'm still doing quite a bit of learning.

Comment: @andrdoiddev In `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`
call `exportDB(getDatabasePath("wines.db"));`

Comment: Like this..? https://pastebin.com/WBJ5dq08 Because if so, it's still giving me the context message.

Comment: @andrdoiddev Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156492/discussion-between-hamed-nabizadeh-and-andrdoiddev).